# How to run commands on SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me to create this table as an example? I am trying to teach myself but I'm having issues, it's easier for me if I can see an example.

The *Costume* table stores information about each costume in inventory.
The *Costume* table includes *CostumeID*, *Description*, *Size*, *RentalPrice*, and *CategoryID* fields.
The *CostumeID* field is unique for each costume and serves as the table’s primary key.
The *Description* field stores the name of the costume, such as pirate or toad.
The *Size* field indicates the size of the costume, such as small, medium, or large.
The *RentalPrice* field stores the costume’s rental price,
and the *CategoryID* field stores the category identification number. The *CategoryID* value is obtained from a list of values stored in the *Category* table.

The *Customer* table stores information about each customer.
The *Customer* table includes *CustomerID*, *LastName*, *FirstName*, *StreetAddress*, *City*, *State*, *Zip*, and *Phone* fields.
As the *CustomerID* field is unique for each customer, this field serves as the primary key for the *Customer* table.

I created this already: (all in order according to the field names provided.)

Field Names-CostumeID, Description, Size, RentalPrice, CategoryID

Data Type- Text, Text, Text, Money, Text

Field *Description* Serves as primary key, Described the costume, Indicate the costume’s size, Stores the daily rental price, Associates the costume with a certain category or group of costumes. Use the Lookup Wizard

Field Size- 5, 50, 5, (none Rental), 5(categoryID)

Comments required for *CostumeID* and *CategoryID*

Comment: What kind of issues are you having? Your title needs to be revised. Your question is how to run commands on Management Studio? How to do a create statement? Or how to structure your table/schema?

Comment: If I understand your question and your comments on @Menelaos's answer correctly, you don't know how to begin writing a `CREATE TABLE` statement. That's fine, of course - everyone starts somewhere - but this site has a question and answer format and that doesn't work very well for detailed explanations or long examples. I think the best thing you can do is find a good SQL tutorial and/or book.

Comment: Sorry, but seems you done nothing for searching for examples by your self. In the network(Google,Bing, ...) millions of examples about SQL syntax(CREATE, UPDATE, SELECT), same as basic rules for design of database structure...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two more tables one being:

Customers, and the other being Categories.
Category ID will be the primary key of categories.
Customer ID will be the primary key of customers

You need to include these keys as foreign keys within your costumes table.
The primary key of your costumes table will be costumeID.

Comment: Yes how to do the Create statement with each aspect for the table is confusing me